# How can I fetch all items from a DynamoDB table without specifying the primary key with java?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm fairly new to Amazon's AWS and its API for Java, so I'm not exactly sure what the most efficient method for what I'm trying to do would be. Basically, I'm trying to setup a database that will store a project's ID, it's status, as well as the bucket. What I'm having trouble with is getting a list of all user without primary key ?. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the 'Scan' operation provided by DynamoDB. It does not need primary key to operate on. But keep in mind that scan operation is very inefficient and needs more read capacity. Read about `Scan` here on it's official doc.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html

If you want to just retrieve all the entries, DynamoDB is probably not a acorrect choice for storing this data.

Comment: "If you want to just retrieve all the entries, DynamoDB is probably not a acorrect choice for storing this data." -Why not?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 for one I think it would be pretty expensive:
Say you have a table with 1,000 items and want to read all the items within one second using the scan operation:  
- assuming each item is less than 4Kb in size  
- assuming you're using eventually consistent reads  
- you would need 500 units of read capacity  
- current pricing is $0.0065/hour to get 50 units of read capacity per second  
- which would cost 365days*24hours*($0.0065*10) = $569.4 per year  
- that price increases linearly with increased table size

Comment: Still cheaper than most RDS options if the table size is kept small. Obviously there is a cliff where that no longer is the case in regards to row count and size. A lot of planning needs to go into it.

Comment: More than what, using a query to limit what is found and returned?  Sure.  But is it any more inefficient than a table scan in a relational database as far as IO hit goes?